# Why is making two corners round slower than make all corners round?

Tags: ios, layer

Edit: Language updated to improve readability.

I made an image view with 2 rounded corners like this:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.photoImageView.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10, 10)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.photoImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

But it is slower than making all the corners round using this code.

```
self.photoImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

Would anyone know what why and how I can improve my '2 corner' code please?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is adding another stage to the drawing. Normally, the background is drawn (with the given cornerRadius) directly to the target, but with a mask specified, it is drawn to a temporary surface, then copied to the target using the mask.

There isn't any built-in functionality for only rounding some background corners in the standard CALayer object.

I do wonder how slow "slower" really is; is this premature optimisation?

Comment: Actually, I use these code in my tableview's cell. So, when I scroll my tableview, I found it's look like lost some frame. So I want to fix it.

Comment: Best solution in that case is probably to make images to put over the corners (specifically, a quarter circle of transparent on a solid colour which matches your background). Images are always faster to render than vectors. You could also try shouldRasterize, but I think that won't help in a table (which does funny things when rendering)